# Buttonmanagement in C# and auto generated button click events

Tags: c#

I need some input on a class that has been bothered me all day. What I want to achieve is listing buttons next to eachother and show them max 8 at the time. So if there is more then 8 buttons I'll use navigation buttons to scroll through the possible buttons.

The problem I have is, since these are generated in a loop - the click events doesn't behave like I want.

This is the class I've made for this:
[Buttonmanagement class](http://pastebin.com/qXtJYLX2)

The problem is probably very easy but I've stared on this way too long! When I first trigger the method drawGroupButtons() I found it easiest too see the problem when you show the buttons in the middle. I can with no problem go in one direction, but as soon as I change direction the problems start to appear.

In my example (in another not attached class) I've used 128 buttons and start generating them from 43 to 57. If I go left in the "menu" I get:
29,43 ->
15,29 ->
0,15

THe above values is the content of p_Start and p_End. This is just how I want it. If you noticed it's different amount of buttons in each step, it is because of the navigation buttons (the first group 0,15 only have a right-button). But when I start going right, the initial values are used (in this case 43,57). So I will jump from 0,15 to 57,71 which is terribly wrong :( It's like the click events doesn't know the changes the other one does. Do anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is finally solved!!!

The error was that navigationbuttons were lying on top of eachother so the solution were actually working but the wrong button was clicked. In case someone want to use this, the only change I did was to move the declaration of the bPrev and bNext variables to the top of drawGroupButtons() and then added Constrols.Remove(bNext) under bPrev scope, and Controls.Remove(bPrev) under bNext scope!

Comment: @Ondrej All code that is needed is attached, so yeah, its "local" but still relevant

Comment: We do not include code on pastebin. Either post here relevant parts or nothing at all. Read rules of the SO first!

Comment: Ahh, yeah sure. I can simply post the code here then :)